# Retrieve the URL from the Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, vba, url, internet-explorer

i am struggling on the following: I try to open an URL(Link), become redirected to a new URL and retrieve this new URL into a Cell in my excel worksheet.

I have written the following code but it is *not* retrieving the new URL and is *not* quitting the Internet Explorer at the end:

```
Sub Get_URL()

Dim ISIN As String
Dim Link As String
Dim IE As Object

ISIN = Range("A1").Value
Link = "https://www.finanzen.net/suchergebnis.asp?_search=" & ISIN

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate Link
End With

Range("A2") = IE.LocationURL
Set IE = Nothing
IE.Quit

End Sub
```

The ISIN in A1 is **KYG875721634**.
I would be very glad if some of you guys could find the problem. Thank you very much!
Greetings, Robin

Comment: Use a proper page load wait or While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <>4:DoEvents:Wend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. Read the comments please:

```
Sub Get_URL()

Dim ISIN As String
Dim Link As String
Dim IE As Object

  'ISIN = Range("A1").Value
  ISIN = "KYG875721634"
  Link = "https://www.finanzen.net/suchergebnis.asp?_search=" & ISIN
  
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate Link
  End With
  'You must wait to load the page
  Do While IE.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
  
  'Range("A2") = IE.LocationURL
  MsgBox IE.LocationURL
  
  'First quit the IE
  'because this step needs the reference ;-)
  IE.Quit
  Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried the code an everything worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

There're two issues in your code:

1. You need to add a wait to load page.

   ```
   Do Until IE.readyState = 4
      DoEvents
   Loop
   ```
2. First quit IE. If you first set IE to Nothing then there will be no reference to IE when quit.

   ```
   IE.Quit
   Set IE = Nothing
   ```

The final code is like this which can work well:

```
Sub Get_URL()

Dim ISIN As String
Dim Link As String
Dim IE As Object

ISIN = Range("A1").Value
Link = "https://www.finanzen.net/suchergebnis.asp?_search=" & ISIN

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate Link
Do Until IE.readyState = 4
   DoEvents
Loop

Range("A2") = IE.LocationURL
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried the code an everything worked fine!